# Install a programming-language to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, development-environment

I installed Visual Studio. The languages Java and C came not with it. 
How can install the languages to the IDE ?

Best Regards

Khashayar

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2015 Community Version.

Answer (score 0):

For java
you can try this : 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93

And you can do c with c++ projects navitely (if you did a custom install without tools, you can still modify your installation)

Comment: I did that.... Visual Studio is giving me hard time though...I can't debug.

Comment: "This perview Version of the Java Debugger only Supports starting execution in a named class; the class Name may be configured in the Project properties on the Debug tab."

What I did, I went on Project, ConsoleApplication1 properties, Debug Tab, wrote pkg/program in the "Start class within Project" field and changed the configuration to "All Configuration" 

I get the error "This Process could not be completed" .

Comment: Are you unable to debug on java or c ? I'm not sure about the fact that Visual Studio is the best choice for Java moreover for begginers (see Netbeans, Eclipse or other tools designed for Java).

Comment: Java. 
Okay, I will download NetBeans. 
Visual Studio is very complex...I have to get to know it better. 

Thought I might as well do Java in VS...anyways appreciate your help.